# Cocoa – Core Data object graph

Tags: cocoa, core-data, object-graph

How do I handle the deletion of the following objects? What should my delete rules look like?

Here's what my object graph looks like:

**Boss**

- Boss-Department has a many-to-many-relationship
- If a Boss is deleted,
  the Departments belonging to that Boss should **NOT** be deleted (but the
  Departments' relationship to this Boss should be deleted)

**Department**

- Department-Employee has a many-to-many relationship
- Department-Boss has a many-to-many relationship
- If a Department
  is deleted, the Employees belonging to that Department should be
  deleted **IF** they don't have a relationship to any other Department

**Employee**

- Employee-Department has a many-to-many relationship
- Employees will never be deleted directly (only through the deletion of a department). Oh happy life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation the Delete rules for your objects should be handled like this

Boss-Department -> Nullify

Department-Employee -> Deny

Department-Boss -> Nullify

Here is what Apple explains the Delete Rules as

> Deny: If there is at least one object at the relationship destination,
>   then the source object cannot be deleted. For example, if you want to
>   remove a department, you must ensure that all the employees in that
>   department are first transferred elsewhere (or fired!) otherwise the
>   department cannot be deleted.
>
> Nullify: Set the inverse relationship for
>   objects at the destination to null. For example, if you delete a
>   department, set the department for all the current members to null.
>   This only makes sense if the department relationship for an employee
>   is optional, or if you ensure that you set a new department for each
>   of the employees before the next save operation.
>
> Cascade: Delete the
>   objects at the destination of the relationship. For example, if you
>   delete a department, fire all the employees in that department at the
>   same time.
>
> No Action: Do nothing to the object at the destination of
>   the relationship. For example, if you delete a department, leave all
>   the employees as they are, even if they still believe they belong to
>   that department.

For more information check out the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)